# Revert all changes done by Kali ppa

Tags: 21.10, wayland

So I followed [this](https://miloserdov.org/?p=3609) guide an installed kali linux repositories  ... Basically I did all these

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
wget 'https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc'
sudo apt-key add archive-key.asc
sudo apt update #Do not apt upgrade, only update
sudo sh -c "echo 'Package: *'>/etc/apt/preferences.d/kali.pref; echo 'Pin: release a=kali-rolling'>>/etc/apt/preferences.d/kali.pref; echo 'Pin-Priority: 50'>>/etc/apt/preferences.d/kali.pref"
sudo apt update
```

The problem now is that, Kali somewhat broke Wayland for me (**wayland is no longer in the clog options of gnome-session)

1. I **DO NOT** have an nvidia or intel GPU so that's not the case (i run amd radeon)
2. `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` already has Wayland enabled
3. I have already tried all other basic stuff like removing the kali ppa from source `sources.list`, rebooting, restarting gdm3 etc

Currently the only graphical way i can use wayland is using this algorithm

1. create a new user and login into the new user with main user logged out
2. from the top right corner, use the `switch user` option and when i choose the main user, this time wayland appears in the options of the clog. But this obviously isnt a solution since the option is no longer present after a reboot

Further, Kali repos have also done more modifications like I get this message in bash when i do certain things

```
┃
┃ This is a minimal installation of Kali Linux, you likely
┃ want to install supplementary tools. Learn how:
┃ ⇒ https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/common-minimum-setup/
┃
┗━(Run: “touch ~/.hushlogin” to hide this message)
```

**Someone please help me revert back everything (including a working wayland) without losing my data under /home (it isnt a separate partition) and user apps**

Comment: After making a mess like this the best answer is reinstall a clean system.

Comment: @David got an exam today ... And i dont have the time to set up all the development environment again from scratch

Comment: That linked page starts with "**this operation may kill your distribution and make it unusable! This is a very real opportunity to break everything due to incompatibility of packages!**" They weren't lying.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had to ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

> Someone please help me revert back everything (including a working wayland) without losing my data under /home (it isnt a separate partition) and user apps

Did you set up a fallback? If not, there is no reverting.

Create a backup of your personal data. You can do that from a new live session if needed. Then use a live session to install Ubuntu by mounting your partitions as you set it up now. So no formatting of / or other partition. This will reset all system related files back to the original leaving /home and personal settings as is. You will need to reinstall all applications you installed yourself. Again: since you left the settings for these on disk this apps will pick up your settings.

Also: it is a good idea to create a new partition and keep your personal files on there and not in /home/. Keep configuration files (as /home/ has those) separate from your personal files. Makes for easier backup and  restoring, plus easier re-installing and also easier installing of a new Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it!

Leaving a note for future refernce

Once you've disabed the kali repo and made sure that changes in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` is done, do these things too

1. `sudo apt purge kali-defaults`. This fixes system instability incase you encountered.
2. Do the changes of Wayland part in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.diverted file too
3. comment down every line that disables wayland in `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` too
4. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`
5. restart gdm3 by `systemctl restart gdm3`

Issues should be fixed by now, just that i was even unlucky.

Though I'm not using an NVidia card, I still had to do some Nvidia stuff to get Wayland working back

6. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` at the end. Then `sudo update-grub`
7. A reboot and my issues were gone